# Isolated eigenvalue of closed operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $L$ is a Fredholm operator, then $LL^\dagger$ is self-adjoint and Fredholm (and this implies its image is closed).

If $0$ is in Spec$(LL^\dagger)$ then it is an isolated eigenvalue.

I don't know why this last statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space. Then $A-\lambda$ is Fredholm if and only if $\lambda$ is a discrete eigenvalue of finite multiplicity or $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set. In fact, if $\lambda$ is an isolated eigenvalue of finite multiplicity, then $A$ restricted to the orthogonal complement of the corresponding eigenspace is bounded away from zero by $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the distance to the remainder of the spectrum.
To see this use the spectral theorem: Write $\|(A-\lambda)\psi\|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (r-\lambda)^2 d\mu_\psi(r)$, where $\mu_\psi$ is the spectral measure corresponding to $\psi$. If $\psi$ is in the orthogonal complement of the eigenspace, then $\mu_\psi$ is not supported at $\lambda$. Moreover, it is in fact not supported on $(\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon)$ and hence $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (r-\lambda)^2 d\mu_\psi(r) = \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus(\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon)} (r-\lambda)^2 d\mu_\psi(r) \geq \epsilon^2 \|\psi\|^2$. Hence we can invert the restriction to the orthogonal complement. Since a self-adjoint operator is closed, this inverse is bounded and closed. Hence $\mathop{Ran}(A-\lambda)$ is closed by the closed graph theorem and $A-\lambda$ is Fredholm of index zero (recall $\mathop{Ker}(A-\lambda)=\mathop{Ran}(A-\lambda)^\perp$).
Conversely, if the multiplicity is not finite or the distance to the remainder of the spectrum is zero, then $A-\lambda$ is not Fredholm since in the first case the kernel is not finite dimensional and in the second case the range is not closed.

Now apply this to your situation.

PS: Here I presume that your operator is closed and densely defined such that the adjoint is well-defined and your product is indeed self-adjoint. If your operators are bounded, you can of course ignore this last point.

Comment: Dear @gerald I don't understand why the restriction of $A$ to the orthogonal complement to the eigenspace is bounded away from 0. Also why this implies that Ran($A - \lambda$) is closed? BTW such a nice book that of "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics"

Comment: The esiest way to see this is using the spectral theorem: Write

Comment: Sorry, it seems I somehow accidentally submitted my comment before it was finished and then was unable to save the final version;-) I now added the details to my answer.